# asp.net mvc html helper problem on nested Master Page

Tags: html, master-pages, helper

Site.Master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>
 
<body>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Menu" runat="server">
                <!-- Menu goes here -->
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>  
</body>
```

Sub.Master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="Menu" runat= "server">
    <% Html.RenderPartial("MainMenu"); %>        
</asp:Content>
```

```
This is the error when the application runs:

The name 'Html' does not exist in the current context
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage"` in the sub.Master directive.